# Datanuclues Merge On HBase Not Working (Serialized (Detached) Objects )

Tags: jpa, hbase, datanucleus

I get the exception when trying to merge an entity whose Id matches the corresponding datastore entity already in HBase:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Object "ai.ilikeplaces.entities.Wall@4aaf0d" being inserted has id "12653" yet an object with this id already exists in the datastore!
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:30
2)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.merge(JPAEntityManager.java:568)
        at ai.ilikeplaces.util.cache.AbstractHCMapStore.store(AbstractHCMapStore.java:39)
        at ai.ilikeplaces.logic.crud.hazelcast.HazelcastWallMapStore.store(HazelcastWallMapStore.java:20)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.concurrentmap.MapStoreWrapper.store(MapStoreWrapper.java:110)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.CMap$1.run(CMap.java:994)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.executor.ParallelExecutorService$ParallelExecutorImpl$ExecutionSegment.run(ParallelExecutorService.java:212)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Object "ai.ilikeplaces.entities.Wall@4aaf0d" being inserted has id "12653" yet an object with this id already exists in the datastore!
        at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.HBasePersistenceHandler.insertObject(HBasePersistenceHandler.java:129)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2371)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.makePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2347)
        at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1798)
        at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1647)
        at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1504)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.merge(JPAEntityManager.java:564)
        ... 8 more
```

When attempting to merge an entity.

The code related to this exception is:

```
        System.out.println("Attempting to store data:" + value);
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("adimpression_ilikeplaces_war_1.6-SNAPSHOTPU_DN");
        System.out.println("Obtained EntityManagerFactory.");

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        System.out.println("Obtained EntityManager.");

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        System.out.println("Began Transaction.");

        em.merge(value);

        System.out.println("Persisted data.");

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Committed Transaction");
```

where

```
em.merge(value);
```

is line 39. That is AbstractHCMapStore.java:39 .

The entity I am trying to merge is a new entity, i.e. created with java new keyword and not fetched from database previously.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **datanucleus.allowAttachOfTransient=true** in **persistence.xml** if you're trying to merge a **serialized** object